# "Удобное, но при этом модное изделие". Нужна ли запятая после слова "модное"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, уточнения

Нужна ли запятая после слова "модное"?

> Удобное, но при этом модное изделие подойдет для мужчин, которые предпочитают вести активный образ жизни.

Answer (score 5):

**Удобное и  при этом модное изделие подойдет для мужчин, которые предпочитают вести активный образ жизни.**

И ― соединительный союз, при этом ― наречие.

**Пояснение**

Откуда в предложении союз НО? Здесь нет значения уступки, иначе это выглядело бы так: удобное, но при этом не очень модное изделие.

**Примеры:**

Сиднейский Мост самый **висячий и при этом самый длинный и красивый** мост в мире.

Системный эффект заключается в возможности производить разнообразную продукцию **быстро и при этом относительно дешево**.

Comment: _самый висячий ... мост_ — разве так можно сказать?

Comment: Если  сказать нельзя, то надо поставить кавычки (необычное значение слова).

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы  правы. Но теоретически можно предположить, что автор считает, будто модность достигается за счет удобства. Тогда НО оправдано :)

Comment: А эту тему раскрывает наречие "при этом", не зря же оно здесь стоит. Два положительных качества сразу: удобное и при этом ещё и модное. А если эти качества противопоставлять, то потребитель будет обижен: он не хочет выбирать между модны и удобным.

Comment: Ну да, хотел получить  удобное, но оказалось еще и модным. Вот досада! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Удобное, но при этом модное изделие подойдет для мужчин, которые предпочитают вести активный образ жизни.**

> Но если определение, присоединяемое подчинительным союзом, является однородным по отношению к предшествующему и не носит характера уточнения (смыслового и интонационного!), то после него запятая не ставится. *Получены важные, хотя и не итоговые сведения.* ([Уточняющие члены предложения](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html))

Дополнение (после обсуждения с Jasmin). В своем ответе я отнесся только к форме предложения, но не к его смыслу. А смысл, при наличии союза *но*, примерно таков. *Автор  считает модность нежелательной добавкой к удобству (об этом говорит союз **но**). Такое сочетание (удобный, но модный) подходит не всем, однако подойдет для мужчин, которые предпочитают вести активный образ жизни.* Вряд ли автор хотел вложить такой странный смысл в свой текст, но так уж получилось.